# How to authorize comma and dot in an input text with JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I'm working with a form which contains an input number (it represents the price of an object).

An input text was created with JSF (The code is not mine):

```
<h:inputText value="#{myObject.unitPrice}" maxlength="10"
                        required="true" >
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{myObject.doCalculateTotalPrice}" />
    <f:validator validatorId="montantValidator" />
    <f:convertNumber pattern="##0.00" locale="en"/> 
</h:inputText>
```

This input works, but our client want to use dot AND comma (don't ask me why!). Is it possible to use a pattern to permit ',' and '.'? Or do should i create a javascript function to replace ',' by '.'?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can create a custom `Converter`. But if asked to do the same, I just would go the JS way.

Comment: What if the customer would want to see his comma back when he/she previews the data?

Comment: @AdrianMitev then the only option would be the store the value as text and create a different property for the number. From a data model point of view, that would be creepy. If the user insists, try to talk the customer out of it. Explain of Internationalization, and that you will let the user set its locale so ALL the numbers (and dates) are shown to him in his locale format.

Comment: And of course, explain to the customer the extra effort (cost/time) that this means

Comment: I have asked to my customer if he wants to see the comma.

Comment: I, too, think that a custom converter is the way to go. You will always have dot OR comma in every locale you choose.

Comment: Thank for all your answer, i have created a custom converter. And i did a simply thing : 
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext pFacesContext, UIComponent pUIComponent, String pValue) {
    if (pValue != null) {
 return Double.parseDouble(pValue.replaceAll(",", "."));
    }
  return null;
}

For the moment, i don't count the digit. But, this first version works!

Comment: Your custom converter will work, but maybe it is better to use regular localization and move all patterns in resource or bean, for example: `<f:convertNumber pattern="#{chProfile.displayLimitedFormat}" />`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you TronchDeYack!

Here it is some code to drop a clear solution.

Customize yourself number type, number format...

**Converter**

```java
@FacesConverter("decimalNumberConverter")
public class DecimalNumberConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject( FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value ) {
        if( value != null )
            return new BigDecimal( value.replace(',','.') );
        return null;
    }

    public String getAsString( FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object ) {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits( Integer.valueOf((String)uic.getAttributes().get("maxFractionDigits")) );
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits( Integer.valueOf((String)uic.getAttributes().get("minFractionDigits")) );
        return nf.format(object);
    }
}
```

**Input**

```xhtml
<p:inputText value="#{bean.myNumber}" >
    <f:converter converterId="decimalNumberConverter" />
    <f:attribute name="minFractionDigits" value="2"/>
    <f:attribute name="maxFractionDigits" value="4"/>
</p:inputText>
```